# Using Ctrl + [ instead of ESC in Vim

Tags: vim

I want to train my self to avoid hitting the <kbd>ESC</kbd> button to exit Insert mode. I want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> instead. But after I put this in my .vimrc

```
inoremap <ESC> <NOP>
```

I can't use Ctrl + [ either.
How can I fix this?

Comment: For some historical detail, do `man ascii` and look at the hex codes.  Input was only with those numbers.  The `CTRL` key's effect took place at the terminal, it just stripped the three high bits from the key code, so holding the `CTRL` key down mapped `[` from `5b` to `1b`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vim cannot distinguish ESC and `Ctrl-[`. If you `:h keycode`, you will see:

```
notation    meaning         equivalent  decimal value(s)    ~
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

<Esc>       escape          CTRL-[   27 *escape* *<Esc>*
```

but you can pull your ESC keycap out. :)

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to do this inside Vim; you'd have to resort to external programs, for example an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) hook on <kbd>Esc</kbd> that is only active inside the Vim application.

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today, even in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>non-alphabetic</kbd> cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>letter</kbd> vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>letter</kbd> cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated [various proposals](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8).

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.